# the problem is delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been deleted since entities were loaded

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The problem is delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been deleted since entities were loaded.

```
using Delete_E.DAL;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace Delete_E
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        UserinfoEntities conn = new UserinfoEntities();
        tableUserinfo otable = new tableUserinfo();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //otable.id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString());
            otable.Name = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            otable.Email = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            otable.Salary= Convert.ToDouble(dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            otable.Gender = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            otable.Speciality = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        }
        public void selectTable()
        {
            dgvData.DataSource=conn.tableUserinfoes.ToList<tableUserinfo>();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectTable();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult qustion = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure to Deleted this Record ","Message Deleted",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (qustion == DialogResult.Yes)
                if (conn.Entry(otable).State == EntityState.Detached)
                    MessageBox.Show("the sata is :"+ conn.Entry(otable).State);
            conn.tableUserinfoes.Attach(otable);
            conn.tableUserinfoes.Remove(otable);
            conn.SaveChanges();
            selectTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `conn.tableUserinfoes.Attach(otable);` and the other statents below it, are always executed, regarless of the `DialogResult` ?

Comment: The DataRow remove method only removes one row according to documentation : "Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the System.Collections.Generic.List<T>."  Do you have shared servers?  See : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm

Answer (score 0):

one of your problems is in the button click event,
it will execute the `attach`, the `remove` and the `selectTable` always, regardless of the `DialogResult`

I think you mean something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult qustion = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure to Deleted this Record ","Message Deleted",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (qustion == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        if (conn.Entry(otable).State == EntityState.Detached)
            MessageBox.Show("the sata is :"+ conn.Entry(otable).State);
        conn.tableUserinfoes.Attach(otable);
        conn.tableUserinfoes.Remove(otable);
        conn.SaveChanges();
        selectTable();
    }
}
```

I have no clue why you are showing that message,
and why you are first attaching before removing.
But anyway, without the {} it would never work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete an object that didn't come from the entity interface. You need to instantiate this `tableUserinfo` object directly from entity (with a query, for example) or at least create it with the ID (primary key).

Please check the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserinfoEntities conn = new UserinfoEntities();
    int selectedUserInfoID; // Keep the currently selected ID of the tableUserinfo object

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the clicked cell's ID (assuming it comes from this expression)
        selectedUserInfoID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString()); 
    }
    public void selectTable()
    {
        dgvData.DataSource=conn.tableUserinfoes.ToList<tableUserinfo>();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectTable();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult qustion = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure to Deleted this Record ","Message Deleted",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (qustion == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             // Ask Entity to generate the proper object with the selected ID (has to be PRIMARY KEY in that table)
            tableUserinfo selectedUserInfo = conn.tableUserinfoes.Find(selectedUserInfoID);

            if (selectedUserInfo != null)
                conn.tableUserinfoes.Remove(selectedUserInfo); // Tell Entity to delete that object (row from database)

            conn.SaveChanges(); // Commit the delete operation
            selectTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option creating the object with the proper ID:

```
if (qustion == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    tableUserinfo otable = new tableUserinfo{ id = selectedUserInfoID };

    conn.tableUserinfoes.Attach(otable);
    conn.tableUserinfoes.Remove(otable);
    conn.SaveChanges();
    selectTable();
}
```